# How to remotely connect to VMware linux machine hosted on Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, remote, vmware, remote-desktop

I would like to remotely connect to a linux (Fedora) vmware machine hosted on a Windows7 desktop machine.

My understanding is that this should work.

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: It does work, but SO is not the proper venue for this question.

Comment: This question is not related to programming unless you mean how to programaticly connect and if so the question should be rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should.  There are actually several different approaches, each with its own pros and cons:

- http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/User_Guide/chap-User_Guide-Sharing_your_desktop.html
- http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/01/connect-to-fedora-14-from-windows-via-remote-desktop-connection-with-xrdp-server/

My favorite solution is to install VNC on both the Windows and Fedora PCs:

- http://www.tightvnc.com/

Comment: How about SSH with forwarded X? It's much more efficient, at least from my experience. You can even get a full shell by executing `gnome-session` or `plasme-desktop`.

Comment: I am going to start by trying out your second solution. It seems like exactly what I need, since I still would like to have a desktop gui.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Vmware, but it should have (like Virtualbox has) an option to set up the network interface.

I always choose bridge and I ssh directly to my linux box. Works no problem.